# What proccessing architecture do I have?

Tags: debian, cpu

I am trying to install Debian on my desktop computer which uses an "Intel Pentium E2200" :
http://ark.intel.com/products/33925/Intel-Pentium-Processor-E2200-1M-Cache-2_20-GHz-800-MHz-FSB

I need to select my processing architecture in order to get started, the following architectures are listed:

```
amd64
armel
kfreebsd-i386
kfreebsd-amd64
i386
ia64
mips
mipsel
powerpc
sparc
```

I think I should choose "amd64" but I'm not totally sure, which architecture should I select?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right: [amd64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64)

kfreebsd-*: Debian GNU/kFreeBSD is a general purpose operating system, an official Debian GNU distribution using the kernel of FreeBSD instead of the Linux kernel.

ia64: the architecture of the Itanium family of 64-bit Intel microprocessors.